# Enter key hook with html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I implemented form in HTML:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="/?do=login" method="post" >
  <table width="50%" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <span id="LoginErr"></span>
        <div>Login:</div>
        <input id="Login" type="text" maxlength="32" name="Login" value="{VAR %LOGIN}"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom">
        <span id="PasswordErr"></span>
        <div>Passoword:</small></div>
        <input id="Password" type="password" maxlength="128" name="Password" value=""/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="javascript:checkLogin()">Enter</a>
      </td>
    </tr>    
  </table>
</form>
```

This is the check and post function (using jQuery):

```
function checkLogin() 
{
  var focused = false;    

  function report_error(field, err)
  {
    $('#' + field + 'Err').html(err);
    if (!focused) 
    {
      $('#' + field).focus();
      focused = true;
    }
  }

  $('#LoginErr').html('');
  $('#PasswordErr').html('');

  $login = jQuery.trim($('#Login').val());
  $password = jQuery.trim($('#Password').val());

  if ($login.length == 0)
    report_error('Login', 'The login field is empty!');

  if ($password.length == 0)
    report_error('Password', 'The password field is empty!');

  if (!focused) 
   $('#loginForm').submit();

}
```

But I have trouble with enter key. When i press this key form is posted without my javascript check.
I need call my function when enter key is pressed and no more action.

Thanx!

Update:
Correct code is:
in form tag need add: `onSubmit="return checkLogin()`
in javascript `if (!focused) $('#loginForm').submit();` need change on `return !focused;`
Thanks to rdamborsky.

Answer (score 1):

use `onSubmit` form event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#loginForm').onSubmit = checkLogin;
});
```

It will be called just before your form's data are actually sent whatever triggers the submit event (click on button, pressing enter within one of fields...)

Comment: I tried this. Yes, checkLogin is called when enter is pressed, but the post method is called too, even if checks is false.

Comment: then if check is false, you need to `return false;` as a result of `checkLogin()` method

Comment: +1 always use a proper form with a submit button and put the validation code on the `onsubmit` event, returning `true` or `false` as necessary. Trying to fake it with links that call `submit()` or key handers will leave you with a less usable, less accessible form.